# UIPickerView select and hide

Tags: iphone, ios, uipickerview

How do you make a `UIPickerView` act like the one with a webview wherein there is a drop down selection box and instead of dropping down like usual websites do, the `iphone` makes it into a `UIPickerView` with all the selections in. When you select one, a check becomes visible beside your selection and changes the value of the drop box. And how do you put the "Done" button on top of the `UIPickerView` to dismiss the `UIPickerView`?

I already know that `[pickerview setHidden:YES]` is the method to use to hide the pickerview. I just don't know how to include the "Done" button in the `UIPickerView`.

Regards,
Chris

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "Done" button is placed in UIToolBar.

Use the below method of UIToolBar for adding the "Done" buttons.

```
- (void)setItems:(NSArray *)items animated:(BOOL)animated {

    UIToolbar*  mypickerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 56)];
    mypickerToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
    [mypickerToolbar sizeToFit];

    NSMutableArray *barItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
    [barItems addObject:flexSpace];

    UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(DatePickerDoneClick)];
    [barItems addObject:doneBtn];

    [mypickerToolbar setItems:barItems animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: what is the purpose of the flexspace? it seems to work even without it? sorry for commenting on an old thread.

Comment: I don't see connection to UIPickerView here.

Answer (score 34):

This piece of code will slide out a picker view as keyboard and attached a done button on top of it. Basically, you want to set a inputAccessoryView with your input field.
You should call this method on a touch down event for your input field.

```
- (IBAction)showYourPicker:(id)sender {

// create a UIPicker view as a custom keyboard view
UIPickerView* pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
[pickerView sizeToFit];
pickerView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
pickerView.delegate = self;
pickerView.dataSource = self;
pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
self.yourPickerView = pickerView;  //UIPickerView

yourTextField.inputView = pickerView;

// create a done view + done button, attach to it a doneClicked action, and place it in a toolbar as an accessory input view...
// Prepare done button
UIToolbar* keyboardDoneButtonView = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
keyboardDoneButtonView.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
keyboardDoneButtonView.translucent = YES;
keyboardDoneButtonView.tintColor = nil;
[keyboardDoneButtonView sizeToFit];

UIBarButtonItem* doneButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done"
    style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self
    action:@selector(pickerDoneClicked:)] autorelease];

[keyboardDoneButtonView setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:doneButton, nil]];

// Plug the keyboardDoneButtonView into the text field...
yourTextField.inputAccessoryView = keyboardDoneButtonView;  

[pickerView release];
[keyboardDoneButtonView release];
}
```

Finally, your Done button calls the "pickerDoneClicked" method, where you should add
`[yourTextField resignFirstResponder];` which will hide the picker view.

Comment: What did i miss out that lead you to put your own answer ?

Comment: sorry, I just think it's nice to have choice of different approach. While one is to have a toolbar at the bottom of the screen, the other is to attach a toolbar on top of the keyboard/uipickerview.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info Jacob. It was really helpful but I believe that the command for the final method is 

[mypicker setHidden:YES]; 

am I correct?

Comment: @Tofu I don't think so. Since the picker is displayed as the text field's inputView when the text field is no longer the first responder the view will be hidden automatically.

Comment: this answer is much better as it shows clearly connection between UITextField and UIPIckerView